# Using Radar Chart inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

In the index.html file we are using, we have this javascript code for the chart.

```
<script src="js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js"></script>

var radarData = {
        labels: ["In Person Call", "RTE", "MobilePush", "Speaker Program"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                pointBorderColor:"rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19]
            }
        ]
    };
  
    var radarOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        legend:{
            display :false
        }
    };
  
    var ctx5 = document.getElementById("radarChart")
    new Chart(ctx5, {type: 'radar', data: radarData, options:radarOptions});
```

But now we are building components and trying to use the same chart inside our component. How to go about doing this? I can use the 'radarData' and 'radarOptions' inside render but how to call the chart in the return statement inside the component with all the parameters passed?

For example in the return statement of the component,

```
return (
<div>
    <"How to get the chart over here?">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this link was helpful for me.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/customizing-chart-js-in-react-2199fa81530a

And I modified my code in the component in this manner:

```
class Name extends Component {
state = {
    id: null
}

chartRef = React.createRef();

componentDidMount() {
    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

    new Chart(myChartRef, {
        type: "radar",
        data: {
            labels: ["In Person Call", "RTE", "MobilePush", "Speaker Program"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    })
}

return (
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChart" ref={this.chartRef} height="180"/>
    </div>
)
```